# EF 6.x AddorUpdate context fails on update

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a scenario where adding a record works fine, but updating a record fails with a validation error when using `context.AddOrUpdate` in EF 6.

The error indicates a required field is missing, however the field actually exists and is populated.

Domain Object

```
public class ExampleSchema {

  public int Id { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [NotMapped]
  public string Password { get; set; }

}
```

**EF Object**

```
public class ExampleSchemaEf : ExampleSchema {

  public string SecurePassword { get; set; }

}
```

We use **AutoMapper** to map between the domain object and the EF object. This mapping is done via a simple `MapFrom` statement which encrypts the password provided by the user when transitioning from the domain object to the EF object.

```
cfg.CreateMap<ExampleSchema, ExampleSchemaEf>().ForMember(e => e.SecurePassword, opt => opt.MapFrom(e => e.Password.Encrypt(config.HashPassphrase)));
```

**The following is the method which writes the changes to the database.**

```
private async Task<int> SaveInternalAsync(TEntity entity, DbContext context {

  var efEntity = DbContextProvider.Map<TEntity, TEfEntity>(entity);
  context.Set<TEfEntity>().AddOrUpdate(efEntity);
  await context.SaveChangesAsync();
  return efEntity.Id; 

}
```

When adding a new record there is no problem. However, updating a record produces an `Entity Validation Error: "Password is required"`. However, if I break the process and inspect the value of efEntity, both Password and SecurePassword exists and are correctly populated. So I do not understand the validation error.

**Note: Adding the following line of code gives me a work-around but I would still like to understand why the EF validator thinks Password is missing for the attempted update.**

```
 context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

**Edit:**

Based on DevNull's answer below, I edited the EF Object so that it does not derive from the domain object and then removed the Required attribute from the Password field. This resolves the validation error without disabling validation. I am still curious, why add works but update does not when the property value exists in both cases.

Comment: Does the table that the entity is being saved to have a required `Password` column?

Comment: No. It does not.

Comment: You're probably not sending the password in on update. and then automapper is setting it to an empty value

Comment: @johnny5 I am sending the value on update, inspecting the entityEf object shows both the Password and SecurePassword properties are populated immediately prior to calling SaveChanges.

Comment: @ScottMoody hmm, interesting, what is the state of the efEntity, are you sure it's modified and not Detached? is there any other entities in the change tracker

Comment: @johnny5 ok, I verified that the state is modified and went looking deeper into the tracked object for the changes. I see that the list of tracked properties does not include Password which is expected. It appears that on a update, the validator is checking that all properties which are marked as required are in the list of tracked properties. This would explain why the validator rejects the update case but allows the insert case. Good to know! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ExampleSchema` has conflicting data annotations on the `Password` property:

```
[Required]
[NotMapped]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

[`[Required]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-annotations#required):

> The Required annotation tells EF that a particular property is
>   required.

[`[NotMapped]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Denotes that a property or class should be excluded from database
>   mapping.

---

It sounds like in your case, you probably just want to remove the `NotMapped` attribute.